# Receiving VHDL code error: object subtype is not locally static using GHDL

Tags: vhdl

I need help solving this error: object subtype is not locally static. The object it is referring to is: instruction_register.

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    
entity scomp is
generic( address_width : integer := 8;
data_width : integer := 16);

port(
clock, reset : in std_logic:= '1';
program_counter_out : out std_logic_vector(address_width-1 downto 0);
register_ac_out : out std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
memory_data_register_out : out std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
memory_address_register_out : out std_logic_vector(address_width-1 downto 0);
memory_write_out : out std_logic
);
end scomp;

architecture rtl of scomp is
type ram is array(integer'(2) ** address_width-1 downto 0) of unsigned(data_width-1 downto 0);
signal ram_block : ram;
attribute ram_init_file : string;
attribute ram_init_file of ram_block : signal is "program.mif";
type scomp_fsm is ( reset_pc, fetch, decode, execute_add, execute_load,
execute_jneg,execute_jneg2, execute_store,
execute_store2, execute_jump );
signal state : scomp_fsm;
signal instruction_register : unsigned(data_width-1 downto 0);
signal memory_data_register : unsigned(data_width-1 downto 0);
signal register_ac : signed(data_width-1 downto 0);
signal program_counter : unsigned(address_width-1 downto 0);
signal memory_address_register : unsigned(address_width-1 downto 0);
signal memory_write : std_logic;
```

There error lies further down in the code within this case statement:

```
when decode =>
case instruction_register( 15 downto 8 ) is
when "00000000" =>
state <= execute_add;
when "00000001" =>
state <= execute_store;
when "00000010" =>
state <= execute_load;
when "00000011" =>
state <= execute_jump;
when "00000100" =>
state <= execute_jneg;
when others =>
state <= fetch;
end case;
```

Comment: `instruction_register` is globally static. IEEE Std 1076-1993 8.8 Case statement "If the expression is of a one-dimensional character array type, then the expression must be one of the following: -- The name of an object whose subtype is locally static". You have string literal choices and use locally static bounds in a slice. You could declare a locally static subtype  - `subtype upper8 is unsigned(15 downto 8);`. and use a qualified expresion - `case upper8'(instruction_register( 15 downto 8 )) is`, or use -2008 which bases choice coverage detection on length.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so readers can replicate the problem and any answers.  Your code won't work with data_width less than 16.